# AWS dynamoDB - Why User and System errors not populating for each table instead of account metrics?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

How to get the errors count for each table to get deep into it?

Usually errors (User & System error) occurs in each DynamoDB table but why it's categorized as 'Account metrics' in Cloud-Watch. So the value is the aggregate of all tables errors in that particular region instead table wise.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Garry.